# How to convert an excel equation to javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I have this kind of long formula in excel and need to convert it to javscript for use on a webpage.

The formula is as follows:

> =IF(B15/Q2<1;0.4*((B15^3)/(Q2^2))-0.09*((B15^2)/Q2)+0.1*B15;B15-(Q2*(0.79*EXP(-0.27*(Q2/B15)))))

`B15` and `Q2` are integers >= 0

In excel when `B15 = 292` and `Q2 = 251` it out puts `135`.

In my attempt to convert it to javascript it out puts 417.  Not even close as you can see.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit-

The formula finds the damage done to a player.  As B15 is the the attack rating and Q2 is the armor the attack has to go through.  The expected damage would be 135 with those numbers

Comment: Would you mind telling us what the formula does (in a math manner like x*(y^2) + 5)?

Comment: Are you sure the Excel formula you shared is correct? Seems to me the semi-colons ";" should be replaced with commas "," to make the formula work.

Comment: Im sure it is correct as it does work.  And i didnt make the formula.  So im not sure how it goes about doing what it does.  I dont know much about excel so I cant really answer much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = 292,
    b = 251,
    c = null;

if(a/b<1)
    c = 0.4*(Math.pow(a,3)/Math.pow(b,2))-0.09*(Math.pow(a,2)/b)+0.1*a
else
    c = a-(b*(0.79 * Math.exp(-0.27*(b/a))))

console.log(c);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3ZJH/

Answer (score 0):

A rough guess, if you converted it rather literally, the `^`s might be causing issues, as those are bitwise XORs in Javascript. You should instead use the `pow` method. For example, for the first instance in your formula would be `pow(B15, 3)`.